# How to Resolve Duplicate Vector Matches in Redis Vector Store Using Langchain Framework?

Tags: redis, langchain, py-langchain, redis-search, redis-stack

I'm currently using Redis Vector Store in conjunction with the Langchain framework. My application is configured to retrieve four distinct chunks, but I've noticed that sometimes all four chunks are identical. This is causing some inefficiencies and isn't the expected behavior. Does anyone know why this might be happening and have any recommendations on how to resolve it?

```
def getVectorStore(database: str, index_name: str = "KU_RULE_05") -> Redis:
    if database not in vectorstore:
        raise ValueError(f"{database} does not exist in vectorstore list in utils.py")

    if database == "Redis":
        VectorStore = Redis.from_existing_index(
            embedding=embedding(),
            redis_url=os.getenv("REDIS_URL"),
            index_name=index_name)

    return VectorStore
```

```
def getRelatedDocs(content: str, database="Redis"):
    VectorStore = getVectorStore(database=database, index_name=index_name)
    RelatedDocs = []

    for index, documents in enumerate(VectorStore.similarity_search(query=content)):
        RelatedDocs.append("{}: {}".format(index + 1, documents.page_content))
    return RelatedDocs
```

We've thoroughly checked for any duplicate documents in the database to see if that could be the cause of the issue, but we found no duplicates.

Comment: you could try VectorStore.similarity_search(query=content, k=1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so most likely you are continuing to use the `from_documents` method in the `getVectorStore` function when you should actually be using the `from_existing_index` method. You're likely re-generating and uploading the embeddings each time, each with a unique UUID, hence the duplicates.

The flow for reusing an index once created (as it is in `from_documents`) is:

1. `from_existing_index` (make sure to pass schema if using metadata)
2. then either use as retriever in a chain `as_retriever` or use the search methods directly, i.e. `similarity_search`.

example

```py
from langchain.vectorstores.redis import Redis

metadata = [
    {
        "user": "john",
        "age": 18,
        "job": "engineer",
        "credit_score": "high",
    },
    {
        "user": "derrick",
        "age": 45,
        "job": "doctor",
        "credit_score": "low",
    }
]
texts = ["foo", "foo"]

rds = Redis.from_texts(
    texts,
    embeddings,
    metadatas=metadata,
    redis_url="redis://localhost:6379",
    index_name="users"
)
results = rds.similarity_search("foo")
print(results[0].page_content)
```

then to init an index that exists you can do

```py
new_rds = Redis.from_existing_index(
    embeddings,
    index_name="users",
    redis_url="redis://localhost:6379",
    schema="redis_schema.yaml"
)
results = new_rds.similarity_search("foo", k=3)
print(results[0].metadata)
```

Notice, I'm passing the schema above. If you're using metadata, you can write out the schema file using the `write_schema` method.

```py
# write the schema to a yaml file
new_rds.write_schema("redis_schema.yaml")
```

I highly recommend going through the documentation for the newer release of the redis integrations as well

https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/redis

Ok now given your code, I'm not positive what's actually causing this error since you're positive you've curated your database contents, but could you try

```py
def getRelatedDocs(content: str, database="Redis"):
    VectorStore = getVectorStore(database=database, index_name=index_name)
    RelatedDocs = []

    docs = VectorStore.similarity_search(query=content)
    for i, document in enumerate(docs, start=1):
        RelatedDocs.append(f"{i}: {doc.page_content}")
    return RelatedDocs
```

If this doesn't work I would try to run simpler examples with your codebase and see if a more trivial example works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But we already use 'from_existing_index method', below is our getVectorStore function code

def getVectorStore(database: str, index_name: str = "KU_RULE_05") -> Redis:
    if database not in vectorstore:
        raise ValueError(f"{database} does not exist in vectorstore list in utils.py")

    if database == "Redis":
        VectorStore = Redis.from_existing_index(
            embedding=embedding(),
            redis_url=os.getenv("REDIS_URL"),
            index_name=index_name)

    return VectorStore

Comment: editing my answer